# How can I get rid of the square brackets and print the output one per line? (python)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to print about 7611 numbers and save it as a txt file.

But when I just print normally

```
    ex.txt

    [[1 2 3 4 
      5 6 7 8
          ...]]
```

A txt file is created as above.

What I want to do is print like :

```
     ex.txt

     1
     2
     3
     4
     5
     .
     .
     .
```

How can I change the form of the result like above?

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using a 2-d array?

Comment: yes. 2-d array.

Comment: As suggested, you can simply flatten the array using .flatten() function and then print it as you would do for normal 1-d array.